# Android Studio Java infix to postfix calculations decimal point gives crash

Tags: android, mobile, calculator, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I was trying to make a calculator for my university homework. to **calculate** the results I use infix to postfix convention. but this code doesn't take only **decimal point (.)** as a result, it crashes whenever I put (.) as input like 1.1+ it crashes. In the operator section there is no part for decimal point this is happening for that. but I was confused about how to resolve this.

run log!
[image]

```
class Solution {
public double calculate(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() < 1) return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    return evalSuffix(inToSuffix(s));
}

public int rank(Character op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+': return 1;
        case '-': return 1;
        case '*': return 2;
        case '/': return 2;
        case '%': return 2;
        case '^': return 3; //you can add more operators
        default: return 0; //priority for '('
    }
}

public List<Object> inToSuffix(String s) {
    Stack<Character> opStack = new Stack<>();
    List<Object> suffix = new LinkedList<>();
    double num = 0;
    boolean numCached = false;
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (char c : chars) {
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            num = num * 10 + (c - '0');
            numCached = true;
        }
        else {
            if (numCached) {
                suffix.add(num);
                num = 0;
                numCached = false;
            }
            if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') continue;
            if (c == '(') opStack.push('(');
            else if (c == ')') {
                while (opStack.peek() != '(') suffix.add(opStack.pop()); //op in () should be added first
                opStack.pop();
            }
            else {
                while (!opStack.isEmpty() && rank(c) <= rank(opStack.peek())) suffix.add(opStack.pop());
                opStack.push(c);
            }
        }
    }
    if (numCached) suffix.add(num);
    while (!opStack.isEmpty()) suffix.add(opStack.pop());
    return suffix;
}

public double evalSuffix(List<Object> suffix) {
    Stack<Double> numStack = new Stack<>();
    double num1 = 0;
    double num2 = 0;
    for (Object o : suffix) {
        if (o instanceof Character) {
            char op = (Character)o;
            num2 = numStack.pop();
            num1 = numStack.pop();
            switch (op) {
                case '+': numStack.push(num1 + num2); break;
                case '-': numStack.push(num1 - num2); break;
                case '*': numStack.push(num1 * num2); break;
                case '/': numStack.push(num1 / num2); break;
                case '%': numStack.push(num1 % num2); break;
                case '^': numStack.push((double)Math.pow((double)num1, (double)num2)); break;
            }
        }
        else numStack.push((Double) o);
    }
    return numStack.pop();
 }
}
```

**Also, you can provide a better solution if you have any!!**

Comment: Share crash log

Comment: @Arul I have added the log and the code photo indicating an error.

Comment: You are returning the values two times at a time, In the function eval() and rank().  The last return statement like in eval() function-> return x+y and in the rank() -> return 0; try to put these inside else if or remove.

Comment: @RakeshSaini update the code with another version but still same error!!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for m!~

```
ExpCalculator{

public static double evalPostfix(String postfixExp){

    int index = 0;
    Stack<Double> arr = new Stack<Double>();
    double result = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < postfixExp.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = postfixExp.charAt(i);
        
        if(c == ' ')
            continue;
          
        else if(Character.isDigit(c))
        {
            double x = 0.0;
            boolean check = true;
            
            while(Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.')
            {
                
                if(c!= '.' && check == true){
                    x = x*10 + (double)(c-'0');
                    i++;
                    c = postfixExp.charAt(i);
                }
               
                else{
                    check = false;
                    x = x + 0.1 + (double)(c-'0')/10;
                    i++;
                    c = postfixExp.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            i--;
            arr.push(x);
        }
        else
        {

            double val1 = arr.pop();
            double val2 = arr.pop();
            switch(c)
            {
                case '+':
                    arr.push(val2+val1);
                    break;

                case '-':
                    arr.push(val2- val1);
                    break;

                case '/':
                    if (val1 == 0)throw new ArithmeticException();
                    arr.push(val2/val1);
                    break;

                case '*':
                    arr.push(val2*val1);
                    break;

                case '^':
                    for(int x = 1; x< val1; x++)val2*=val2;
                    arr.push(val2);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new ArithmeticException();
            }
        }
    }
    return arr.pop();
}

public static String infixToPostfix(String exp){
    String result = "";
    Stack<Character> arr = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <exp.length() ; i++) {
        char c = exp.charAt(i);
        
        if(precedence(c)>0){
            
            while(arr.isEmpty()==false && precedence(arr.peek())>=precedence(c)){
                result += arr.pop();
            }
            result += ' ';
            arr.push(c);
            
        }else if(c==')'){
            char x = arr.pop();
            while(x!='('){
                result += x;
                x = arr.pop();
            }
        }else if(c=='('){
            arr.push(c);
        }else{
            
            result += c;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <=arr.size() ; i++) {
        result += arr.pop();
    }
    return result;
}


static int precedence(char c){
    switch (c){
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 2;
        case '^':
            return 3;
    }
    return -1;
}

}
```